# Conditional expected value problems

Tags: probability-theory

We know that $(X,Y)$  have density $g(x,y)=2e^{-x-2y}$ for $x,y\geq 0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ elsewhere. The task is to calculate:

1. $E\left(\frac{X+Y}{Y+1}|Y\right)$
2. $P(X-Y>0|Y \leq 0)$
3. $E(X|\min(X,Y))$

First we find joint density $g(x|y)=e^{-x}1_{x>0}$ and $E\left(\frac{X+Y}{Y+1}|Y\right)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x+y}{y+1}e^{-x} dx=1 $.

Now $P(X-Y>0|Y \leq 0)=P(x>0)=1-P(x\leq 0)=1-F_x(0)=1$.

These two steps where quite easy but I have no idea what to do with the minimum. Could you show me how to deal with the  $E(X|\min(X,Y))$?

Comment: How do you get $1$ for the first one? For the second one, you are conditioning on a zero probability event. How did you take that into account?